# Service fabric cluster on AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, azure-service-fabric

Just trying to know if anyone has ever installed a service fabric cluster on AWS before and is there any documentation available for that?

Comment: Really easy to find documentation with a quick google search. Unfortunately, this type of question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: The official document talks about standalone cluster.  It is not enough to know how to install or configure the cluster to support auto scaling so the adding/removing nodes can be automated (for e.g. AWS elastic scaling).  This is crucial for cloud deployment.  Otherwise, the service fabric usage is quite limited when auto scaling is a must.

Answer (score -1):

See official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-anywhere) on how to set up a standalone cluster.

> Service Fabric provides an install package for you to create standalone Service Fabric clusters on-premises or on any cloud provider.

Comment: This should be, at best, a comment (it's just a link). You basically googled for the OP.

Comment: @DavidMakogon FYI I actually knew the answer and only needed the link for the quote, so included the link. Fair enough, could answer it as a comment, still that would be an answer. Following your logic, I should reply the guy just like you did, which IMO is silly. You downgraded me, so good for you.